# Can I uninstall a program or driver from Windows 7 recovery tools?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, bsod

I just installed Windows 7. The first thing I did after desktop was run a full system update. Upon reboot, BSOD. The message doesn't display long enough for me to read what it says - it flashes for less than a second, reboots, and goes into recovery mode. The same thing happens if I try to boot into safe mode.

I know I can restore to before the update, but it was a huge update and I really don't want to do it all over again. However, the latest restore point lists a few suspicious drivers. Mostly I am concerned about AMD (HDC) 03/31/2013 1.2.001.0337.

Is there any way I can get rid of it without restoring or booting to the desktop?

If not, can I disable it either via regedit or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If restore fails, load the recovery environment "command prompt" and enter:

```
Del C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml
```

Exit recovery environment and restart the PC. The desktop should load.

Comment: Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately) I have no way of knowing if this works and won't until I reformat, reinstall Windows and do a full system update again. Sounds like a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "disable" command to disable drivers and services. Use "listsvc" to get a list of the services and drivers installed.

Comment: `listsvc` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I believe that was only in Windows XP.